# Running Classic ASP site on IIS7.5

Tags: asp-classic

I've tried everything I can think of (and read online) and hit a brick wall.

Bought a new PC, Windows 7 and turned on IIS7.5 and Classic ASP. Downloaded my classic asp site and database (an Access database - yes I know, Access!). I downloaded my whole site wwwroot for local developing and testing.

Any asp page residing in the top level directory (localhost/index.asp) runs fine in the browser. But click on a link to any page within a directory (eg localhost/blah/index.asp) gives me a 404 error.

The files are DEFINATELY there. If I create a simple test asp page and place it in a directory, it works fine in the browser. And it's not a coding issue - the site works online and on my old XP machine.

Could it be to do with permissions of the files and folders when they were downloaded (BTW, I tried downloading via filezilla and FTPrush, but it made no difference). I'm no expert on PCs, and I've already experienced a few problems with permissions (and I'm logged into PC as Administrator)

Any ideas please?

Comment: [Maybe something to do with enabling parent paths?](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-parent-paths-are-disabled-by-default)

Answer (score 0):

So are the files based in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\blah? Does c:\inetpub\wwwroot\blah\index.asp exist?

Try giving IISUR and IIS_IUSRS admin access over the folder and its contents.